# Laravel: How can we know the error when sending HTTP request

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use a Http method to reactivate user's subscription, using HTTP request, but there might be two problems that exist (the json code would return two potential errors):

1. Reactivating a canceled subscription with an invalid payment profile

   - Given you have a canceled subscription with ID "1000"
   - The subscription has an invalid payment profile
     Send a PUT request to https://sample.chargify.com/subscriptions/1000/reactivate.json
   - The response status should be "422 Unprocessable Entity"

The subscription should be canceled with the following response

```
  {
      "errors": ["The credit card on file could not be charged."]
  }
```

2. Attempting to reactivate an already active subscription

   - Given you have an active subscription with ID "1000"
   - Send a PUT request to https://sample.chargify.com/subscriptions/1000/reactivate.json
   - The response status should be "422 Unprocessable Entity"

The subscription should be active with the following JSON response

```
  {
      "errors": ["Cannot reactivate a subscription that is not marked 
                    \"Canceled\", \"Unpaid\", or \"Trial Ended\"."]
  }
```

I am new to Laravel, therefore I would like to know the way I can detect the error when sending the request to the server, but right now I only have one option (without a valid if statement) which cannot detect the problem.

I think an if statement would do but I'm not sure how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the if statement will work if:

```
if (isset(response()->error)){

    // error message

}   else {

    // success message

}
```